# Read header into environment variable in Apache 2.2?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, http-headers, mod-headers

I want to process a request header using a custom rewrite map.

Therefore I want to have the content of the header in an environment variable.

I have not found a way to do that with mod_headers and/or mod_rewrite.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: mod_rewrite should be able to do this. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mod_rewrite example for the request header "X-Forwarded-For":

RewriteRule .* - [E=X-Forwarded-For:%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For}]